# Is it possible to detect text field clicks using Google Tag Manager (GTM)?

Tags: google-tag-manager

The idea is to check if someone started filling in the form but hasn't submitted it. Is it possible to detect specifically text field clicks? 
Thank you!

Comment: It seems you would want to record an event (in GA) when a form submission has been started. You could also record an event when a form submission is completed. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is. You could use CSS selectors and page URL logic to specifically target the form you want to get the data for.

Create a GTM click trigger on "some clicks", using a CSS selector and URL/page path filter to ensure the event only fires on the form you want it to fire on.

Example of CSS selector: https://jsfiddle.net/ajsn/qe492r5o/

```
<input type="text" value=""></input>
document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').addEventListener('click',function(){
    alert("clicked");
})
```

If you are using Google Analytics, you send all the clicks in as an event. There you can track engagement with the form. You can create a segment that looks at people who have completed the form and also engaged, alternatively those that engage with the form but don't complete. You could also create goals and track a funnel for drop off, or do something using GA Bigquery transfer service.

Simo has a great post on CSS Selectors which might be helpful: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/css-selector-guide-google-tag-manager/

Comment: Could you please also help to detect script buttons' clicks and physical keypresses (if it's possible)? Many thanks!

Comment: GTM has an auto event listener for clicks on the page. Would suggest you use that if you want clicks. Tracking keystrokes is discussed here and links to Simo again: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/forum/AAAAnP_FwdILxEuGSAXcTg/?hl=fil